# Simple true or false questions, analysis

Tags: real-analysis

True or false?

a) If $\lim_{x \to x_0}=L$ and $f$ is defined in $x_o$, then $L=f(x_0)$

b) If $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)=L$, then $\lim_{x \to x_0} 3[f(x)-4]^2 = 3(L-4)^2$

c) If $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)g(x)=0$, for any function $g$ that is determined in the same range as $f$

What I've tried:

a) I think it's true, since $f$ is determined in $x_0$.

b) Having trouble with this one, can I get $\lim_{x \to x_0}$ inside $[f(x)-4]^2$ ?

c) I think it's true, since $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)g(x)= \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) \lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)= 0 * \lim_{x \to x_0} g(x) = 0$

Comment: You got 0 correct answers! The first is false (it is true only for continuous functions!), the second is true because $3(x-4)^2$ is continuous, while the third is false since it could be that $g$ is unbounded.

Comment: What do you mean by $g$ is determined in the same range as $f$?  They have the same domain, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

**a)** Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x\ne 0, \\ 0, & x=0.\end{cases}$$

**c)** Consider $f(x)=x$ on $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty).$ It is $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0.$ What is $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x)$$ when $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}?$